# Error at "The PHP exention OAuth 1.2.3 must be installed"

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I using PHP sample SDK for integrate QUICK book payment API.
But I am getting error:

> The PHP exention OAuth 1.2.3 must be installed

But I am already installed OAuth.dll in WAMP extension folder enabled in php.ini file and restarted it.

But still no success.

Comment: Please copy+paste your errors - I am sure PHP does not misspell it!

Answer (score 1):

There's two php.ini files for WAMP, one for command line use and one for apache. Please enable the extension in the phpForApache.ini file as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain me more on where to find apache.ini file to enable DLL file.

Comment: It depends on your version, either in the wamp/bin/apache/apache_ver/bin/php.ini or wamp/bin/php/php_version/phpForApache.ini. I'm not sure why you just didn't google it